# Extend FactoryGirl within Rspec test

Tags: rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to make use of FactoryGirl functions `create` and `build` in my rspec tests *without specifying the FactoryGirl namespace every time*: `create` instead of `FactoryGirl::create`.

I thought I could do this by extending FactoryGirl as follows, but I always get a NoMethodError.

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.extend FactoryGirl
end

describe 'my thing' do

  it 'should be ok' do
    obj = create :my_factory
  end

end
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach to do this is as follows:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

This is documented in https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md under "Using Factories"